# query only the last 2 latest period in MS access for calculation

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I have a table that goes like this. I want to query this table with only the rows that have the latest 2 period date, grouped by **resident** and **rotation**. Ultimately I would like to get the ave of Q1, Q2 and so on with the calculation only done on 
'Feb-15' and 'Jan-15' rows for this example.

```
Name | Period | Rotation | Q1 | Q2 ...
 x     Dec-14
 x     Jan-15
 x     Feb-15
```

How should I go about doing this? On MS Access 2010 here.

Comment: provide your query,  and if possible please explain in details.

Comment: If you create table with one additional column like Period_INT INTEGER, which will store int value for Dec-14 to 201412,Jan-15 to 201501, and so on or One column for Auto Increment value.